How to mock constructors using mockito?
I am testing a method some class which has a new constructor call of BuildingBlockDbHandler.class. I was earlier using powermock to mock constructors like this way -
BuildingBlockDbHandler blockDbHandler = mock(BuildingBlockDbHandler.class); PowerMockito.whenNew(BuildingBlockDbHandler.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(blockDbHandler);
but now I am migrating to mockito as in higher springboot version powermock support is removed, how can I do the same thing in mockito.
I tried using mockedConstruction but could not find correct way of using it to stub constructor calls.
I expected to stub constructor calls without using powermock.

I always get uneasy when I have to mock a constructor call. Why do you need to do that? Can't you use the real thing? Or replace the constructor call with a factory call?

@Chaosfire i tried that way but mockito is not able to detect construction of local object I got I am getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 on mockConstruction.constructed().get(0);

@Arjun .constructed() returns the mocks created during the test, depending on where you use it, there are no mocks yet. Most of the time you shouldn't need to get created mocks (personally I have never needed them). Notice the 2nd argument in the example (the lambda function), that's where you need to configure the mock (as done in the example).
